# change the color of the div after click inside the input. (css only no js )

Tags: html, css

I have an email input inside a div and I want to change the color of the div after click inside the input. (css only no js )

i dont want use JS for this so I want to know is it possible with css only ?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Please provide some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this but it is kind of a workaround:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div class="outside">
     <label>email: </label>
     <input class="input" type="text" />
     <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="outside">
    <label>password: </label>
    <input class="input" type="password" />
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.outside {
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px;
    background: red;
}

.outside * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.outside > .input:focus ~ .inside {
    background: blue;
}

.outside > .inside {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

    top: 0;
    right: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: yeah its ok but i want to change the container color when i click on input

Comment: edited the answer, now it should work just how you want.

Comment: yeah it works correctly <3